# my smooth scroll is not working on click it is directing me to a page of the name of my id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use smooth scroll in my web page but it's not working.

My Jquery code:

```
$('a[href*="#"]').not('[href="#"]').not('[href="#0"]').click(function(event) {
  console.log("jquery");
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
      &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) {
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1');
            $target.focus();
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

and my HTML file code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-nav">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-center mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active nav-li slideRight">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#home"><font face = "Helvetica" size = "4">Home</font></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active nav-li slideRight">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about"><font face = "Helvetica" size = "4">About</font></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active nav-li slideDown">
              <img src="img/vhlogo.png" class="navbar-brand size_hide" height="60px" width="60px"/>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active nav-li slideLeft">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery"><font face = "Helvetica" size = "4">Gallery</font></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active nav-li slideLeft">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><font face = "Helvetica" size = "4">Login/SignUp</font></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

And like this i gave the id's
on clicking on link in navbar it is redirecting to the url with the last value /#gallery but that is not a file

```
<div id="gallery" class="container">
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor creating a [mcve] with relevant HTML and frameworks - for example if you use BootStrap, you can copy the libraries from here: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: I guess you just need to change `.click(function(event) {` to `.click(function(event) { event.preventDefault()`

Comment: now it is not redirecting me but the scroll is still not working after clicking on the link nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

actually i was using  for linking my file. therefore it was redirecting me to the base url+ id name.